# c++ getline() function

Tags: c++

I dont' quite understand how this function works.

I wrote a simple programming reading one line with getline().

for example:

```
ifstream in;
in.open("example.txt");
string line;
getline(in, line);
cout << line << endl;
```

When I tried to run this program I received an error message like this.

```
`assign1_2.cpp:33:20: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'    to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'
```

I simply don't understand what went wrong here. Please help!. I am a newbie to c++.

Comment: Could you show us the entire program, the error is not there. Where do you call `atoi`?

Comment: It doesn't look like the error message is related to the code you've posted (it's complaining about an `std::string` being passed to `atoi()` instead of a constant pointer to `char`). Is this code really in `assign1_2.cpp` around line 33?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what compiler did you use? I think the fact that the `std::string` type is given as `'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'` is pretty neat!

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Newer GCC does that.

Comment: thanks all for taking an interest. I was not trying to use atoi or any other integer from a file. It was simply a line of string.

Comment: @user1047092:  The takeaway from that message is that you were trying to compile the file "assign1_2.cpp" and line 33 of that file had the error.  That's where you'll find the problem.

Comment: The problem lies in the part of the program you *didn't* show us. Please post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the error you are seeing. http://sscce.org/

Comment: You should use `std::stoi` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't show the code with the error, but the error says you tried to call `atoi` with an argument of type `std::string`. `atoi` takes a C string (`man atoi`), so you need to call it like:

```
atoi( line.c_str() );
```

Comment: sorry about the inadequate info. the text file contains text below.





assign1_2.cpp:33:20: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'

and I was tried to compile with GCC. 
I was not , however, trying to use atoi here.

Answer (score 0):

Which function are you trying to call? The gnu 'C' getline function or istream::getline?

istream::getline has the following signature

```
istream& istream::getline( char* str, streamsize count)
istream& istream::getline( char* str, streamsize count, char delim )
```

So you call should be something like:

```
char* buf[1000]
in.getline( buf, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `string line` to `char line[2000]`
like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char line[2000];
    fstream in;

    in.open("example.txt",ios::in);

    while(!in.eof()) 
    {
          in.getline(line,2000);
    }   

    in.close();
    cout <<line;
    cout <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```